# Controling a PC via tcp/udp commands necat/socat

Tags: netcat, socat

I want to config a PC with necat or socat to execute a script when I tell the server to do this.

I have an old app cappable to send simple message UDP prefered.

The message is stored in a playlist.

[image]

example

Let's say I want to send a message to open a macro/script to the PC that is running netcat/socat

```
"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\script.bat"
```

**the server needs to listen on a port.
and execute the program when the command its received**

how I do this? I don't know how to start I found nothing on internet.

PS.  please don't mind UDP security or reliability; it's a LAN thing, and I don't need the server to tell me anything back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic use of `netcat`.  But this is `unix.SE` so my answer will be completely in unix.

Note: `netcat` has different names on different distros:

- `netcat`: alias to `nc` on some distros
- `nc`: GNU netcat on linux or BSD netcat on *BSD
- `ncat`: Nmap netcat, consistent on most systems

Options between different versions of `netcat` vary, I'll point out where different version may behave differently.  Moreover, I strongly recommend installing the nmap version of netcat (`ncat`) since its command line options are consistent across different systems.

I'll be using `ncat` as the netcat name thorough the answer.

### TCP

To use TCP to control a machine through `netcat` you have two options: using a named pipe (which works with all versions of netcat) and using `-e` (which only exists in the linux version, or, more exactly, `-e` on *BSD does something completely different).

On the **server side** you need to perform either:

```
mkfifo pinkie
ncat -kl 0.0.0.0 4096 <pinkie | /bin/sh >pinkie
```

Where: `0.0.0.0` is the placeholder for "all interfaces", use a specific IP to limit it to a specific interface; `-l` is listen and `-k` keep open (to not terminate after a single connection).

Another option (on linux/ncat) is to use:

```
ncat -kl 0.0.0.0 4096 -e /bin/sh
```

To achieve the same result.

On the **client side** you can use your app or simply perform:

```
ncat <server ip> 4096
```

And you are in control of the shell on the server, and can send commands.

### UDP

UDP is similar but has some limitations.  You cannot use `-k` for the UDP protocol without `-e`, therefore you need to use the linux/ncat to achieve a reusable socket.

On the **server side** you do:

```
ncat -ukl 0.0.0.0 4096 -e /bin/sh
```

And on the **client side** (or from your app):

```
ncat -u <server ip> 4096
```

And once again you have a working shell.

Comment: thank you I finnaly learn what a shell is
ive got it worked with `nc -L -v -p 4096 -e cmd.exe`
_-k option is not available on windows_
**the UDP mode is not working.**
`nc -L -u -v -p 4096 -e cmd.exe`
any idea why?

and soory i not a linux user, :(

Comment: @MihaiPopescu - I cannot tell you on the switches for MS windows, I have not a single MS machine to test it, sorry.  But `ncat` should be consistent even across MS windows, and should be included on [nmap's bundle for MS windows](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows)